# What is happening with Tie::LevelDB? It automatically compacts the database?

Tags: perl, leveldb

I'm testing `Tie::LevelDB` with a randomly created database,

```
tie my %hash, 'Tie::LevelDB', "/run/shm/testdb";
for ( 1 .. 10000 )
{
    my $key = '/123/' x 55 . $_;
    my $val = { 
        ctime => 123,
        mtime => 123
    };

    $hash{$key} = freeze ($val);
} 

say $_ for keys %hash;
```

When the script is finished I checked the disk space of `/run/shm/testdb`, which is `3.3 MB` in total.

Then I commented out the `for ( 1 .. 10000 )` loop, only did the `say` part, and I checked the `testdb` folder again, it only takes `156 KB` now!

Weird, right? Can anyone please explain that to me? I'm not suffering a data loss.

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause of the behavior you're seeing, but apparently LevelDB does a lot of shuffling of data between files and data compaction. See [Leveldb file layout and compactions](http://leveldb.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/impl.html) for details.